# Screen Width and Height Android

Tags: android, android-layout

what minimum-sdk and target-sdk to be set so that we can check for the android version and use the either `getSizez()` or `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` depending on the version of android.
my current minimum sdk is `8` and target is `13`.

what I am doing currently is

```
    Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) 
    {
        width=display.getWidth();
        height=display.getHeight();
        // only for android older than gingerbread
    }
    else
    {
        display.getSize(point);
        width=point.x;
        height=point.y;
        Log.I("Width",Integer.toString(width));
        Log.I("Height",Integer.toString(height));
    }
```

but it is giving error over display.getSize(point)
The error it gives is

```
The method getSize(Point) is undefined for the type Display..
```

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When checking on the developer.android.com site, it says that the display.getSize(point) is only valid for android version 13 and above  so I would change your initial if statement from

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)

to

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13)

Comment: the if part is not giving any error @gbotha but the error is at display.getSize()..and this where the error i mentioned above comes.. its a compile time error and not the runtime error.

Comment: That's because gbotha is right, GINGERBREAD != 13.  getSize(point) doesn't exist until 13, which is HONEYCOMB_MR2.